# SwiperJS preventing slideNext unless a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe

I would like to prevent slideNext unless there is a certain action (JS confirm - click on Yes button)..

```
swiperV.on('onSlideNextEnd', function () {
swiperV.slidePrev();
});
```

If I make swipe it will first display the next slide and then jump back which is not okay.. If i use onSlideNextStart it will not work. In a way I am trying to recreate tinder-like UX where there the next slide would not be shown until an action with the first one is performed.

Does anyone has any experience with this?

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Answer (score 0):

I think - not 100% sure - that when `onSlideNextEnd` is fired, it's too late; you can only go back.

To avoid this go forward-stop-go back situation, IMO you have to change the design:

do `swiperV.stopAutoplay()` until confirmation you are talking about is done;
and `swiperV.startAutoplay()` when confirmation when confirmation occurs.

Comment: The problem is that Autoplay is for automatic slides switching.. There is also an issue with onSlideNextStart, because it does not have any effect on onSlideNextEnd.. Simply said I see no way how to stop the animation, before a certain action is fully performed.